# Mobile-Safari stopped asking me to update passwords

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I use a wifi hotspot where, after I connect, I have to fill in my username and password in a loginscreen. 
My username stays the same, but the password changes quite often.

Safari used to detect when I entered a different password, and offer me to update my saved password. Now not any more...

How do I enable this?

Comment: I tried removing the password in the hope it would ask me to save the password when I enter it. But it doesn't happen.
"AutoFill" is enabled in the safari settings.

Comment: On "normal" websites I don't seem to have this problem, but on the WIFI login page I do have this. Maybe that page has somehow disabled the possibility to store passwords recently?

Comment: The only way I know how to do it is to directly modify the keychain database.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings→Safari→'Passwords and AutoFill' and enable 'Name and Passwords'.

Comment: Already enabled.